# How to do authentication using SOAP?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, authentication, soap

How do I authenticate users with SOAP?

Will I have to require the user to send his username and password with every SOAP request and I authenticate him against the database?

Doesn't that seem to cause unnecessary queries?

Answer (score 10):

An easier way would be to authenticate on the first query, build a session record on the server side containing the remote IP address and a token that you give to the client as an authToken.  Then have the client pass this authToken in future queries.  This authToken has to match the internal session data you keep about the client, but would allow you to avoid having to make round-trips to the database just to do authentication.

That said, @Marcus Adams has a good point below with regard to stateless-ness.  There are people out there pushing all sorts of [SOAP security models](http://www.whitemesa.com/soapauth.html).  [WS-Security](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) is the current state of the art, here.  They all work by putting authentication information in the SOAP header - after all, that's why a SOAP message contains both a header and a bodypart.

Comment: This is the usual way as far as I know. It would also allow the sign-in to have a SSL encrypted endpoint (to obtain the key) and use non-encrypted endpoints for data requests (if the data may be send unprotected of course).

Answer (score 4):

Having the user send the username and password with each request is the way that I've seen most SOAP interfaces implemented. Actually, I've not seen any other implementation other than the *API key* idea, which is just trading a Username and Password for some other token.

SOAP interfaces should be stateless, like HTTP, so this seems like a normal consequence.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example of how I use an API validation in the header:

file **portfolio-lookup-client.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
class portfolioLookupAuth 
{ 
    public $apiKey; 
    public function __construct($key) 
    { 
        $this->apiKey = $key; 
    } 
} 
$apiKey = "123456"; 
$url = 'http://mysite.com/php5soap/portfolio-lookup.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 

// Create the header 
$auth  = new portfolioLookupAuth($apiKey); 
// SoapHeader::__construct ( string $namespace , string $name [, mixed $data [, bool $mustunderstand [, string $actor ]]] ) 
$header = new SoapHeader($url, "APIValidate", $auth, false);   

  try {

    $result = $client->__soapCall("getPortfolioByName", array("portfolioName" => "WQAM"), NULL, $header);       
    print_r($result);

    print "<pre>\n"; print "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
    print "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n"; print "</pre>";    

  } catch (SoapFault $exception) {

    echo 'Exception Thrown: '.$exception->faultstring.'<br><br>';  

  }

?>
```

file **portfolio-lookup-server.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache

class PortfolioLookupService {

    private $apiKey = '123456';

    private $portfolios = array(
            'WPOW' => 'Power 96 party station.',
            'WQAM' => 'Sports radio site.',
            'WJBR' => 'Cool sites for bands.',
            'WKIS' => 'Kiss Country 2',

  );

  public function APIValidate($auth){

    if($auth->apiKey != $this->apiKey){
        throw new SoapFault("Server", "Incorrect key");
    }

  }

  function getPortfolioByName($portfolioName) {
    //print_r($portfolioName); exit();
    if (isset($this->portfolios[$portfolioName])) {
      return $this->portfolios[$portfolioName];
    } else {
      return 'Portfolio name "'.$portfolioName.'" not found.';
      //throw new SoapFault('code', 'string', 'actor', 'detail', 'name', 'header');
      throw new SoapFault("Server","Unknown Name '$portfolioName'.");      
    }
  }  

  function getPortfoliosAll() {
      return $this->portfolios;
  }    

}

$server = new SoapServer("portfolio-lookup.wsdl");
$server->setClass("PortfolioLookupService");
$server->handle();

?>
```

file **portfolio-lookup.wsdl**

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>

<definitions name='PortfolioLookup'

  targetNamespace='http://example.org/PortfolioLookup'

  xmlns:tns='PortfolioLookup'

  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'

  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'

  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<message name='getPortfolioByNameRequest'>
  <part name='portfolioName' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='getPortfolioByNameResponse'>
  <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>


<message name='getPortfoliosAllRequest'>
  <part name='portfolioName' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='getPortfoliosAllResponse'>
  <part name='Result' type='xsd:array'/>
</message>


<message name='APIValidateRequest'>
<part name='apiKey' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='APIValidateResponse'>
<part name='testReturn' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>



<portType name='PortfolioLookupPortType'>

  <operation name='getPortfolioByName'>
    <input message='tns:getPortfolioByNameRequest'/>
    <output message='tns:getPortfolioByNameResponse'/>
  </operation>

  <operation name='getPortfoliosAll'>
    <input message='tns:getPortfoliosAllRequest'/>
    <output message='tns:getPortfoliosAllResponse'/>
  </operation>

    <operation name='APIValidate'>
    <input message='tns:APIValidateRequest'/>
    <output message='tns:APIValidateResponse'/>
    </operation>

</portType>

<binding name='PortfolioLookupBinding' type='tns:PortfolioLookupPortType'>

  <soap:binding style='rpc'
    transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>


  <operation name='getPortfolioByName'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:PortfolioLookup#getPortfolioByName'/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:PortfolioLookup'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:PortfolioLookup'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </output>
  </operation>


  <operation name='getPortfoliosAll'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:PortfolioLookup#getPortfoliosAll'/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:PortfolioLookup'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:PortfolioLookup'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </output>
  </operation>  




</binding>

<service name='PortfolioLookupService'>

  <port name='PortfolioLookupPort' binding='PortfolioLookupBinding'>
    <soap:address location='http://mysite.com/php5soap/portfolio-lookup-server.php'/>
  </port>

</service>

</definitions>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a custom SOAP header and exchange authentication credentials in the header. Read values from header and authenticate.